# Configure IsConcurrencyToken(value) with annotations in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, optimistic-concurrency, rowversion

I want to be able to use an attribute on a Row Version property of a model to enable or disable Optimistic Concurrency in the `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method of my `DbContext` in *EF Core 7.0.0*. I was able to make it work in *.NET Framework 4.8* but I need to do it in an EF Core project as well.

I have an interface for entities which have a `Version` property called `IVersionedEntity` and I want to use a custom attribute where I can define if I want to enable or disable optimistic concurrency.

The attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true)]
public class LockAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool IsEnabled { get; private set; }

    public LockAttribute(bool isEnabled = true)
    {
        IsEnabled = isEnabled;
    }
}
```

And I know I can achieve the enable-disable behavior inside the `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method with this extension method in *ASP.NET (.NET Framework)*:

```
public static void ConfigureLocking(this DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Types<IVersionedEntity>().Configure(configuration =>
    {
        var versionPropertyInfo = configuration.ClrType.GetProperty("Version");
        var lockAttribute = versionPropertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<LockAttribute>(true);
        if (lockAttribute != null)
        {
            configuration.Property(entity => entity.Version).IsRowVersion().IsConcurrencyToken(lockAttribute.IsEnabled);
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is, that the `ModelBuilder` class inside *EF Core* is quite different and I do not know how to configure something like this using that class.

Comment: EF Core version?

Comment: @IvanStoev EF Core 7.0.0. Thanks for pointing it out. I added the info to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF Core 7.0+ it can be done relatively easy with a custom [Model building convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#model-building-conventions). In fact all predefined EF Core data annotations are handled with convention classes similar to this:

```cs
public class LockAttributeConvention : PropertyAttributeConventionBase<LockAttribute>
{
    public LockAttributeConvention(ProviderConventionSetBuilderDependencies dependencies) : base(dependencies) { }

    protected override void ProcessPropertyAdded(IConventionPropertyBuilder propertyBuilder, LockAttribute attribute, MemberInfo clrMember, IConventionContext context)
    {
        if (attribute.IsEnabled)
        {
            propertyBuilder.ValueGenerated(ValueGenerated.OnAddOrUpdate, fromDataAnnotation: true);
            propertyBuilder.IsConcurrencyToken(true, fromDataAnnotation: true);
        }
    }
}
```

Helper method for registering it:

```cs
public static ModelConfigurationBuilder AddLockAttributeSupport(this ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    configurationBuilder.Conventions.Add(sp => new LockAttributeConvention(
        sp.GetRequiredService<ProviderConventionSetBuilderDependencies>()));
    return configurationBuilder;
}
```

and finally call it from `ConfigureConventions` override:

```cs
configurationBuilder.AddLockAttributeSupport();
```